# Unable to access RDS mysql from Jbdc

Tags: mysql, jdbc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm able to connect to mysql running on AWS RDS in a VPC with a mysql client on ec-2 instance by specifying the host and port number.

When I try to access it using jdbc, I get this exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:Communications link failure
```

I believe the security group is correctly configured because I'm able to access the RDS mysql using mysql-client on ec2. How do I debug ?

Comment: Quick clarification : is the JDBC client running on your EC2 instance as well? Same VPC? On premises?

Comment: Yeah on same EC2 instance. I have only one vpc and only one security group. @SébastienStormacq

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your security groups assigned to your instance have permissions in the rds security group.  Also make sure your vpc (if you are using one) has proper network acl's allowing ingress and egress traffic through.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact your clients (MySQL and JDBC) apps are running on the same instance, it excludes many low level routing issues you might face.

I would double check the following list (in no particular order)

- are you trying to connect to the same ip address from the CLI and JDBC?
- are you connecting to the same port number?
- are you using DNS for one connection and ip address for the other? If yes, check DNS resolution.

As you said, it is unlikely to have misconfigured the security group or the network acl as CLI is connecting. But it is worth a triple check too.

Comment: I had to create another security group, not the default one for the ec2 instance and then associate with the RDS. That fixed the problem.